# how to catch the unauthenticated response 401 from django rest api in react native

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, react-native

Here in views.py

```
class StockList(APIView):
#authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

def get(self,request):
     stocks = Stock.objects.all()
     serializer = StockSerializer(stocks,many=True)
     return Response({'user': serializer.data,'post': serializer.data})
def post(self):
     pass
```

Here if token is not valid then it doesnt send any data..
so in react native I have to patch that error and show their invalid credentials.
So here is my react.js file

```
  componentDidMount() {
  return fetch('http://10.42.0.1:8000/stocks/',
  {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `JWT ${"eyJhbGciOiIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InNhbSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjYxLCJlbWFpbCI6IiIsImV4cCI6MTUwNDAxNTg4M30.o_NjgPNsxnLU6erGj5Tonap3FQFxN3Hh_SsU6IvLO9k"}`
  }
})

  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
    console.log(responseData.detail);
    let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      sa: ds.cloneWithRows(responseData.post),

    }, function() {

    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

here if json data is not provided then show some error..
how could I accopmlished that.
thank you.

Comment: @BünyaminBennyGenel (Error decoding signature ) error is showing on console for that line of code.

Comment: Is the error decoding signature the response from django or a react js exception?

Comment: @SachinKukreja might be django..

Comment: Then that `responseData` may have a status code in it, which you can check if it is 401 or not.

Comment: On your django api you can return an alrenative result json with an error and description. This way you can check responseData.error exist or not.

Comment: @BünyaminBennyGenel but how ? please try to write it on above views.py code.

Comment: I'm not good with django so mine was just a suggestion but I gues you can do something like this. `def get(self,request):
     //here check if request has the auth header stocks = Stock.objects.all()
     serializer = StockSerializer(stocks,many=True) // here check if the stocks count is more than 0
     return Response({'error':true,'description': 'Auth failed!'})`

Comment: I'm not very familiar with react native, but I would discourage you from changing the behaviour of your django-rest view. It's actually good practice and correct to send back an HTTP 403 Forbidden response to the client when it's not authorised to fetch a resource. You should catch that in your javascript: where you have `then(response)`, the `response.info().status` is actually giving your the error so you should branch there and not assume `response.json()`